# Encode/Decode Script that decodes and encoded string twice

Tags: java, arrays, encoding

Basically have a simple process that involves mapping letters and numbers 2 spaces forward so an `A` would encode to `C` , `1` to `3` and such. There is wraparound for so `Z` would encode to `B` and `0` would encode to `2`. The encode works fine, but after the first cycle of the loop the decode seems to map back **4 spaces** instead of **2**. Here's the code, let me know what you guys think the problem is.

> **Encode/Decode**

```
public class EncodeDecode {
    private String[] originalList;
    private String[] encodedList;
    private String[] decodedList;

    public EncodeDecode(String[] oL) {
        originalList = oL;
        encodedList = originalList;
        decodedList = originalList;
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < oL.length; cnt++) {
            encodedList[cnt] = originalList[cnt];
        }
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < oL.length; cnt++) {
            decodedList[cnt] = originalList[cnt];
        }
    }

    public String encode(String originalWord) {
        //Maps every character in original word to 2 positions forward w/ wrap around.
        String result = "";
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < originalWord.length(); cnt++) {
            result += forwardMap(originalWord.charAt(cnt));
        }
        encodedList[0] = result;
        return result;
    }

    public String decode(String codedWord) {
        //Maps every character back 2 spaces w/ wrap around
        String result = "";
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < codedWord.length(); cnt++) {
            result += backMap(codedWord.charAt(cnt));
        }
        decodedList[0] = result;
        return result;
    }

    public char forwardMap(char ch) {
        char result = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if (result == 'a') return 'c';
        if (result == 'b') return 'd';
        if (result == 'c') return 'e';
        if (result == 'd') return 'f';
        if (result == 'e') return 'g';
        if (result == 'f') return 'h';
        if (result == 'g') return 'i';
        if (result == 'h') return 'j';
        if (result == 'i') return 'k';
        if (result == 'j') return 'l';
        if (result == 'k') return 'm';  
        if (result == 'l') return 'n';
        if (result == 'm') return 'o';
        if (result == 'n') return 'p';
        if (result == 'o') return 'q';
        if (result == 'p') return 'r';
        if (result == 'q') return 's';
        if (result == 'r') return 't';
        if (result == 's') return 'u';
        if (result == 't') return 'v';
        if (result == 'u') return 'w';
        if (result == 'v') return 'x';
        if (result == 'w') return 'y';
        if (result == 'x') return 'z';
        if (result == 'y') return 'a';
        if (result == 'z') return 'b';  
        if (result == '0') return '2';
        if (result == '1') return '3';
        if (result == '2') return '4';
        if (result == '3') return '5';
        if (result == '4') return '6';
        if (result == '5') return '7';
        if (result == '6') return '8';
        if (result == '7') return '9';
        if (result == '8') return '0';
        if (result == '9') return '1';
        if (result == ' ')
            return ' ';
        else 
            return '$';     
    }

    public char backMap(char ch) {
        char result = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if (result == 'c') return 'a';
        if (result == 'd') return 'b';
        if (result == 'e') return 'c';
        if (result == 'f') return 'd';
        if (result == 'g') return 'e';
        if (result == 'h') return 'f';
        if (result == 'i') return 'g';
        if (result == 'j') return 'h';
        if (result == 'k') return 'i';
        if (result == 'l') return 'j';
        if (result == 'm') return 'k';  
        if (result == 'n') return 'l';
        if (result == 'o') return 'm';
        if (result == 'p') return 'n';
        if (result == 'q') return 'o';
        if (result == 'r') return 'p';
        if (result == 's') return 'q';
        if (result == 't') return 'r';
        if (result == 'u') return 's';
        if (result == 'v') return 't';
        if (result == 'w') return 'u';
        if (result == 'x') return 'v';
        if (result == 'y') return 'w';
        if (result == 'z') return 'x';
        if (result == 'a') return 'y';
        if (result == 'b') return 'z';  
        if (result == '2') return '0';
        if (result == '3') return '1';
        if (result == '4') return '2';
        if (result == '5') return '3';
        if (result == '6') return '4';
        if (result == '7') return '5';
        if (result == '8') return '6';
        if (result == '9') return '7';
        if (result == '0') return '8';
        if (result == '1') return '9';
        if (result == ' ')
            return ' ';
        else 
            return '$';     
    }

    public String[] getEncodedList() {
        return encodedList;
    }

    public String[] getDecodedList() {
        return decodedList;
    }
}
```

> **Tester**

```
public class EncodeDecodeTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"abcd", "abcd", "abcd"};
        EncodeDecode ec = new EncodeDecode(list);

        String[] encode = ec.getEncodedList();
        for (int index = 0; index < encode.length; index++) {
            System.out.println("Encoded: " +ec.encode(list[index]));
            System.out.println("Decoded: " +ec.decode(list[index]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is object references on `String[]`, change this

```
encodedList = originalList;
decodedList = originalList;
```

to

```
encodedList = new String[originalList.length];
decodedList = new String[originalList.length];
```

Comment: That made no effect on the outcome of the decode. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: On second thought, that made even the first decode back map 4 spaces instead of 2 spaces. Still have no idea what is causing this but that had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

NOtice that in your main function you are calling a decode on the actual string and not on the encoded string. so your program is working properly if the initializations are correct as Elliot pointed.

```
for (int index = 0; index < encode.length; index++)
{
    System.out.println("Encoded: " +ec.encode(list[index]));
    System.out.println("Decoded: " +ec.decode(ec.encode(list[index])));
}
```

and that will give you your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Ending up finding the answer after enough tinkering around with things and bouncing ideas off my roommates.

Changed this:

```
public String decode(String codedWord)
{
//Maps every character back 2 spaces w/ wrap around
String result = "";
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < codedWord.length(); cnt++)
    {
        result += backMap(codedWord.charAt(cnt));
    }
    decodedList[0] = result;
return result;
}
```

To this:

```
public String decode(String codedWord)
{
    //Maps every character back 2 spaces w/ wrap around
    String result = "";
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < codedWord.length(); cnt++)
        {
            result += backMap(encodedList[0].charAt(cnt));
        }
        decodedList[0] = result;
    return result;
}
```